# How to solve SQLException - Data conversion error in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables that are connected via class name (1:n).

Domain: Product (1)

Domain: HistoryPrice (n)

Product

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product extends AbstractBaseDomain<Long> {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    @Column(name ="name", unique = true)
    private String name;
```

HistoryPrice

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "historyPrice")
public class HistoryPrice extends AbstractBaseDomain<Long> {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="product")
    private Product product;
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface HistoryPriceRepository extends JpaRepository<HistoryPrice, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT h.product " +
            "FROM history_price h " +
            "INNER JOIN product p ON h.product = p.name " +
            "WHERE p.name = :name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<?> findProductByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

This is my Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/historyPrice")
public String searchForProducts(Model model, @RequestParam String namePart) {
    List<?> productList = historyPriceService.findProductName(namePart);
    model.addAttribute(HISTORYPRICE_VIEW, productList);
    return HISTORYPRICE_VIEW;
}
```

This is my SQL output of my table creation:

```
2019-04-11 18:39:20 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table history_price (id bigint not null, version integer, price decimal(19,2) not null, valid_since timestamp not null, product bigint not null, primary key (id))

2019-04-11 18:39:20 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table product (id bigint not null, version integer, current_price decimal(19,2) not null, manufacturer varchar(50), name varchar(50), primary key (id))
```

This is my shortened error that I always get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Datenumwandlungsfehler beim Umwandeln von "HAMMER"
Data conversion error converting "HAMMER"; SQL statement:
SELECT h.product FROM history_price h INNER JOIN product p ON h.product = p.name WHERE p.name = ? [22018-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "HAMMER"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I do not know whether my problem is in my repository or somewhere else.

Maybe someone can give me a the right solution or a good hint.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the problem ? Update your question with stating the problem.

Comment: I edited my question with my stacktrace.

Comment: What is value of `name` you have passed ` [22018-197]`?

Comment: The value of *name* is when debugging *HAMMER*.

Comment: You are using `@Table(name = "historyPrice")` annotation for your `HistoryPrice` class and in your query you are using `history_price` and also it's missing `h.product.name` in your inner join.

Comment: And also you are calling findProductName(namePart)  not findProductByName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem indicated by your stacktrace is your join. You try to join `h.product` which is the id of the product object internally to `h.product.name` which is a string. Spring tries to parse the string as number afterwards thus resulting in the NumberFormatException.

I assume you want to get the HistoryPrice objects. Thus you have three options in your repository:

1. Use native query as you do now but fix tablenames and join, I assume this could work:

```
"SELECT h.* " +
"FROM historyPrice h " +
"INNER JOIN product p ON h.product = p.id " +
"WHERE p.name = :name"
```

2. Use a JPQL query:

```
"SELECT h " +
"FROM historyPrice h " +
"INNER JOIN product p " +
"WHERE p.name = :name"
```

3. Use the method name to let spring data generate your queries:

```
List<HistoryPrice> findAllByProductName(String name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working now. I chose your second example and furthermore I fixed my my @Table name.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any stack ?
Can you copy the error ?

In your log stack you should see some caused by label which will give you the place where the exception is throwed

Comment: Don't think this should be submitted as an answer. Seems more of a comment/question.

Comment: Requests for clarifications should be asked as a comment to the question.

Comment: @JWoodchuck, I hope he is not having  enough reputation (50) to comment on a question.

Comment: no reasons for down-voting here, still a valid comment. Due to SO limitations he cannot post his comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the native query you are trying to equate a product object with a string name.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT h.product " +
            "FROM history_price h " +
            "INNER JOIN product p ON h.product.name = p.name " +
            "WHERE p.name = :name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<?> findProductByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

If the Product Entity contains a name variable, then the above query might execute.

Comment: I am sorry, but it did not work: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feld "H.PRODUCT.NAME" nicht gefunden
Column "H.PRODUCT.NAME" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT h.product FROM history_price h INNER JOIN product p ON h.product.name = p.name WHERE p.name = ? [42122-197]